# Create Custom View?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiview

How to create Custom View like this
[image]

Comment: you try some code and ask any problem

Comment: i can creat it with custom table view but i have one label 
and i have alot of data to display

Comment: It's voted down because you don't share what you have already tried. See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

take a look at [GCRetractableSectionController](https://github.com/gcamp/GCRetractableSectionController). Maybe it can handle the behavior you need, just check out the example project provided with it.

Comment: sorry Nenad I Haven't reputation to vote up :$